# what language is dotnet executable written in?

Tags: executable, cil, .net

I thought it would be Common Intermediate Language, but in notepad it does not look like that at all. Does it just look uglier in reality than in tutorials? Or is it some bytecode form that is further compiled from CIL?

Comment: yeah, methinks it will be a binary representation!

Comment: This may be an unusual question, but it's not so far off base for someone just learning .NET. I don't think it deserved the downvotes. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

It's CIL is the name of the binary format, not of the "assembler" you're thinking of.

Can you possibly imagine that .NET assemblies would be text files?

Comment: I can imagine it.  I can imagine many things!  But alas, I cannot fly.

Answer (score 1):

A .NET executable is a binary file that has a PE header (same as a native executable, but with slightly different values). The PE header tells the OS to load the CLR, which in turn loads the assembly.

The content beyond the header is a binary representation of the CIL code, plus some metadata and other stuff. The text you see in tutorials is the text representation of CIL, in much the same way that the assembly language code you see in a tutorial about assembly language programming is just the text representation of the binary machine code.

See http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2010/7/12/inside-net-assemblies-part-1.html (among many others) for more information.

Comment: A .Net executable does not have the same format as a native executable.

Answer (score 0):

A .Net executable is usually not written, it is compiled from another language such as C#, F# or VB.Net.

The contents of a .Net executable can be viewed with the ILDASM tool.

The contents are first a manifest which is used for reflection, signatures or other meta-code purposes.

Secondly there are the MSIL instructions themselves. These are in a kind of bytecode format, but ILDASM will show you what the instructions are.

And there are sometimes resources such as imagery, sounds or other content packed into the executable.

The executable is just-in-time compiled to native code either during installation (I think this is uncommon), or as a precursor to execution. The resulting native code can be stored for reuse. (This is what I was told during PDC 2001, might be "out of date".)